Striping a dynamic table
I have a dynamic table that is pulling in rows based on ccss class. All of the rows are set to display:none until they are called in. I want to have alternate row colors for readability (white and gray alternating). When I pull the rows in they keep their color that they were assigned when the entire table is present. I have seen other topics on this but the code is not working for me.
Code


var show = document.querySelectorAll(".C");
for (let i = 0; i < show.length; i++) {
  if (show[i].style.display === "none") {
    show[i].style.display = "none";
  } else {
    show[i].style.display = "table-row";
  }
}
.new-table tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.new-table tbody tr {
  display: none;
}
<table class="new-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="C">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="C">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="D">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




What is the purpose of the if (show[i].style.display === "none") { show[i].style.display = "none"; -- that makes little sense...

Note that .style only returns inline styles, not styles inherited from CSS. You need to use getComputedStyle() to get inherited styles.

It would help if you put some text in the table, so you can see the effects of your style assignments.

If you want to use CSS selectors like :nth-child(...) or :nth-of-type(...) to style your rows based on their position, then you cannot exclude rows by changing their style, because they will still be counted by these selectors.
But you can rename the elements from <tr> to <tr-hidden> and back while keeping their content, as demonstrated by the following snippet. The tr:nth-of-type(...) selector counts only the <tr> elements.


document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  for (var tr = event.target; tr && tr.nodeName !== "TR"; tr = tr.parentElement);
  if (tr) rename(tr, "tr-hidden");
});

function showAll() {
  document.querySelectorAll("tr-hidden").forEach(function(tr) {
    rename(tr, "tr");
  });
}

function rename(elem, name) {
  var newElem = document.createElement(name);
  newElem.append(...elem.children);
  elem.replaceWith(newElem);
}
tr:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

tr-hidden {
  display: none;
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Click a row to hide it.
<button onclick="showAll()">Show all rows.</button>



